# iPhone-SDK:Questions about iPhone RingTone and Video access:

Tags: iphone

I have two questions here.
1.) Is it possible to access ring tones/put our custom ring tones programmatically using our client app in iPhone? Does the latest SDK support?

2.) A client iPhone app - Is it possible to download a Video file from server and put into iPhone device any of the folder (or) Video folder?

Please reply if you know the details...

Clave/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't currently access
   user-installed ringtones, or the
   default system sounds.
2. Your application only has access to
   its own "sandbox" of directories,
   which includes folders for
   Documents, Library/Preferences, tmp,
   and the application bundle itself. 
   If your app downloads a video, it
   cannot place it in the
   iTunes-managed video library (ie,
   you can't make it appear in the
   "Videos" application for iPod touch
   or the "iPod" application on an
   iPhone).